# Linking library from Xcode Workspace causes "File is already being linked" dialog to appear

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an Xcode (11.4.1- though this happened in 11.4 and 11.3) workspace. That workspace is composed of multiple iOS Swift static libraries. One of the libs: *lib(A)* needs to use another lib *lib(B)* located in the same workspace.

If I just try to `import` the module from some source file in *lib(A)* the compiler won't be able to find the symbols. Fair enough for "Find Implicit Dependencies" to work as I understand it, I have to `Link Binary With Libraries`; I can accept that, so I explicitly link it:

For *lib(A)* I go to its target and select `Link Binary With Libraries` under its `Build Phases` and select *lib(B)* from the workspace browser. When I do that I receive a warning dialog:

**File is already being linked**

[image: warning dialog]

If I press **Cancel** it still adds the selected item under `Link Binary With Libraries`, but now things build. Why the warning?

The same applies if I were to also add a Unit Testing target to the project for *lib(A)*. If I explicitly link the required static libs, I get that warning. Pressing cancel adds the item, and things work.

Now, "things working" with Xcode is tempting just to back away slowly and take that for what it's worth. However, I'm curious what does that warning mean then/why is it there?  Clearly, according to the compiler, the linking is necessary since it does not compile without it. When adding the linking though it seemingly complains about it.